# Bash command to get the last occurence of a tag in a XML structure

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I have below a sample XML structure:

```
<root>
<id>1</id>
<name>abc</name>
<id>2</id>
<name>def</name>
<id>3</id>
<name>ghi</name>
</root>
```

I am trying to achieve the one single following job:

> Retrieve the text value of the last occurrence of an id tag in the structure. (Should output 3 in this case).

Can you please help?

I have tried using sed but could not get it to output 3. :D

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Please post valid XML.

Comment: If you're parsing XML in a shell script, use the `xmlstarlet` utility.

Comment: If the format is always like that, `grep '<id>' filename | tail -1` will find the last `<id>` line, then you can extract the number from it.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, it helped!

Answer (score 2):

You can use xpath queries that traverse an XML file or string.

For example:

```
xpath -q -e '//root/id[last()]/text()' file.xml
```

---

```
xpath
```

is an executable/command that takes a query and an XML.

-q stands for quiet, meaning you only get what you asked for in the stdout.

-e comes right before a query string.

// stands for a root to start searching.

last() is what you'd expect -1 to do :).

text() takes only the value and doesn't print it surrounded by tags.